# AWS Cloud Watch Custom Metrics for Concurrent users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I got a apache site running in EC2 and would like to trigger Autoscale , " Whenever concurrent users increase, number of servers need to be increased."

I can configure Load balancer and ASG but could not find any metrics for number of users.

What custom metric i need to use to achieve my request?

Comment: I will use APPLICATION ELB with this metric ..

Answer (score 1):

If by "concurrent users" you mean "concurrent connections" then there is the `ActiveConnectionCount` metric in the `AWS/ApplicationELB` namespace.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#load-balancer-metrics-alb